# You cannot define a correlation name 'review_summary' more than once

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have this issue, and I have tried resolving it and cannot find any possible solutions.

```
{
    "0":"You cannot define a correlation name 'review_summary' more than once",
    "1":"
        #1 Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Select->_join('left join', array('review_summary' => 'review_entity_su...'), &Zend_Db_Expr#0000000077bc05d70000000064152d93#, array('reviews_count' => &Zend_Db_Expr#0000000077bc05100000000064152d93#, 'rating_summary' => &Zend_Db_Expr#0000000077bc05160000000064152d93#), NULL) called at [vendor\/magento\/zendframework1\/library\/Zend\/Db\/Select.php:378]\n
        #2 Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(array('review_summary' => 'review_entity_su...'), &Zend_Db_Expr#0000000077bc05d70000000064152d93#, array('reviews_count' => &Zend_Db_Expr#0000000077bc05100000000064152d93#, 'rating_summary' => &Zend_Db_Expr#0000000077bc05160000000064152d93#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-review\/Model\/ResourceModel\/Review\/Summary.php:112]\n
        #3 Magento\\Review\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Review\\Summary->appendSummaryFieldsToCollection(&Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor#0000000077bc04ad0000000064152d93#, 1, 'product') called at [vendor\/magento\/module-review\/Observer\/CatalogProductListCollectionAppendSummaryFieldsObserver.php:57]\n
        #4 Magento\\Review\\Observer\\CatalogProductListCollectionAppendSummaryFieldsObserver->execute(&Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#0000000077bc05110000000064152d93#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:88]\n
        #5 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(&Magento\\Review\\Observer\\CatalogProductListCollectionAppendSummaryFieldsObserver#0000000077bc05120000000064152d93#, &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#0000000077bc05110000000064152d93#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Invoker\/InvokerDefault.php:74]\n
        #6 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault->dispatch(array('instance' => 'Magento\\Review\\O...', 'shared' => false, 'name' => 'review'), &Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Observer#0000000077bc05110000000064152d93#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Event\/Manager.php:66]\n
        #7 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager->dispatch('catalog_block_pr...', array('collection' => &Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor#0000000077bc04ad0000000064152d93#)) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/Event\/Manager\/Proxy.php:95]\n
        #8 Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy->dispatch('catalog_block_pr...', array('collection' => &Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor#0000000077bc04ad0000000064152d93#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:483]\n
        #9 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->initializeProductCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:116]\n
        #10 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->_getProductCollection() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-catalog\/Block\/Product\/ListProduct.php:357]\n
        #11 Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct->getIdentities() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/Layout\/LayoutPlugin.php:75]\n
        #12 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\Layout\\LayoutPlugin->afterGetOutput(&Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor#0000000077bc2efa0000000064152d93#, '          <scrip...') called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:146]\n
        #13 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n
        #14 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', array(), array(array('layout-model-cac...'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Layout\/Interceptor.php:52]\n
        #15 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Layout\\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Page.php:258]\n
        #16 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page->render(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000077bc2cc10000000064152d93#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Result\/Layout.php:171]\n
        #17 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000077bc2cc10000000064152d93#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n
        #18 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000077bc2cc10000000064152d93#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n
        #19 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000077bc2cc10000000064152d93#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n
        #20 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000077bc2cc10000000064152d93#), array(array('result-messages', 'result-builtin-c...', 'result-varnish-c...'), array('updateBodyClass'))) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/View\/Result\/Page\/Interceptor.php:130]\n
        #21 Magento\\Framework\\View\\Result\\Page\\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Response\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000077bc2cc10000000064152d93#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:120]\n
        #22 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n
        #23 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:261]\n
        #24 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000077bc2cc30000000064152d93#) called at [index.php:39]\n",
    "url":"\/jewelry\/womens.html",
    "script_name":"\/index.php",
    "report_id":"6113a484182b27f74ad4cfa478552e8a9dcbb6f99350139971a19f67bd2a7b15"
}
```

Comment: You can't use same alias multiple times.

Comment: Hi @ZealousWeb, thanks for taking your time and answering. I'm quite new to Magento, so what do you mean by the same alias?